# Form with two buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to create multiple forms which have two buttons, each will submit the form to different script, one via ajax and second one will just submit the form.

```
<?php foreach($objects as $object) : ?>      
<div class="card-body">
   <form id="edit-form" action="#" method="POST">
      <input name="subject" value="<?=$object['subject']?>" type="text" id="title" class="input-xxlarge">
      <textarea id="content" name="content" rows="25"><?=$object['content']?></textarea>
      <button type="button" id="send-button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
      <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

First I am trying to get the current form, but I have problem with that. `console.log` shows something only on the first form, if I click on the buttons from other forms then It will do nothing.

```
$('#send-button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.defaultPrevented;
        $form = $(this);
        $url = $form.attr('action');
        $data = $form.serialize(); console.log($form);
        console.log($url);
    });
```

Is it because my button has same ID for every form ?

Comment: e.preventDefault(); and ID MUST be unique

Comment: But how do I use the selector when I will have dynamic ID ?

Comment: Use a class!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="button">send</button>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<form method="POST" action="#">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="button">send</button>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

js:

```
$("form").each(function() {
  var form = this;
  $(form).find('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(form);
    console.log(this);
  })
});
```

this will add events on every form you have on your page, `button` will submit form via script and `submit` will just submit it. also here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h84vvb82/3/) to play with

Comment: One with script and one just submits

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h84vvb82/

`send` submit form with script
and `submit` just submits it
am I wrong?

Comment: But you do not need to attach the event handler to the submit since the type="button" does not submit and OP wants to just submit on type="submit"

Comment: then this is it https://jsfiddle.net/h84vvb82/3/ ??
form submits via script if you click button and just submits when you hit enter or `submit`

Comment: Sure - but that is not the code you have in your answer. Post the code in the answer instead of in comments. the code in your answer will stop submission of all forms

Answer (score 2):

You shouln't use ID's multiple times on the same page. Try to use a class for that case. Also as stated in the comments use `e.preventDefault();` to stop the event.

`$(this)` will result in the `#send-button` beeing targeted. To access the form you need to find the closest `form` element like this:

```
$form = $(this).closest('form');
```